# How to use procedure parameters in merge statement

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, parameters, upsert

i'm creating a procedure to update/insert a table using merge statement(upsert).now i have a problem: using procedure parameters i have to do this upsert.

procedure xyz( a in table.a%type,b in table.b%type,....)
is 
some local variables;
begin
merge into target_table
using source_table --**instead of the source table, i have to use procedure parameters here**
on (condition on primary key in the table)
when matched then
update the table
when not matched then
insert the table ;
end xyz;
so how to use procedure parameters instead of source table in merge statement?? or
suggest me a query to fetch the procedure parameters and use it as source table values.

help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi raskart, checkout new version, this should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maby something like

```
DECLARE V_EXISTS NUMBER;
BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_EXISTS FROM TARGET_TABLE WHERE PK_ID = :ID;

    IF V_EXISTS  > 0 THEN
        -- UPDATE
    ELSE
        -- INSERT
    END IF;
END;
```

Also, you may try to use so-called tempotary table (select from DUAL)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (N NUMBER(2), NAME VARCHAR2(20), ADRESS VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1, 'Name1', 'Adress1');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(2, 'Name2', 'Adress2');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(3, 'Name3', 'Adress3');
SELECT * FROM TEST;
-- test update
MERGE INTO TEST trg
USING (SELECT 1 AS N, 'NameUpdated' AS NAME, 
  'AdressUpdated' AS ADRESS FROM Dual )  src                
ON ( src.N = trg.N )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET trg.NAME = src.NAME,
        trg.ADRESS = src.ADRESS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (src.N, src.NAME, src.ADRESS);
SELECT * FROM TEST;
-- test insert
MERGE INTO TEST trg
USING (SELECT 34 AS N, 'NameInserted' AS NAME, 
  'AdressInserted' AS ADRESS FROM Dual )  src                
ON ( src.N = trg.N )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET trg.NAME = src.NAME,
        trg.ADRESS = src.ADRESS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (src.N, src.NAME, src.ADRESS);
SELECT * FROM TEST;
DROP TABLE TEST;
```

see [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_20647073.html)

Comment: Hi coldice,
Thanks for the reply..
I'm looking for a query such that it uses the procedure parameters directly , instead of source_table/view in merge stmt. This query should supply the values(i.e parameters) After the Using keyword in merge statement.

Comment: Hi coldice, i tried using the temporary table method,but it shows error saying "ora:00969: missing ON keyword".

Answer (score 2):

I know that I'm eight years late to the party, but I think that I was trying to do something similar to what you were doing, but trying to Upsert based on parameters passed into a stored procedure that returns an empty string on success and an error on failure back to my VB Code. Below is all of my code along with comments explaining what I did, and why I did it. Let me know if this helps you or anyone else. This is my first time answering a post.

```
PROCEDURE UpsertTSJobData(ActivitySeq_in IN NUMBER,
  Owner_in In VARCHAR2,
  NumTrailers_in IN NUMBER,
  ReleaseFormReceived_in IN NUMBER,
  Response_out OUT VARCHAR2) AS

  err_num NUMBER;
  err_msg VARCHAR2(4000);

  BEGIN
    --This top line essentially does a "SELECT *" from the named table
    --and looks for a match based on the "ON" statement below
    MERGE INTO glob1app.GFS_TS_JOBDATA_TAB tsj
    --This select statement is used for the INSERT when no match
    --is found and the UPDATE when a match is found.
    --It creates a "pseudo-table"
    USING (
      SELECT ActivitySeq_in AS ActSeq,
        Owner_in As Owner,
        NumTrailers_in As NumTrailers,
        ReleaseFormReceived_in As ReleaseFormReceived
        FROM DUAL) input
    --This ON statement is what we're doing the match on to find
    --matching records. This decides whether it will be an
    --INSERT or an UPDATE
    ON (tsj.Activity_seq = ActivitySeq_in)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      --Here we UPDATE based on the passed in input table
      UPDATE
        SET OWNER = input.owner,
          NUMTRAILERS = input.NumTrailers,
          RELEASEFORMRECEIVED = input.releaseformreceived
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      --Here we INSERT based on the passed in input table
      INSERT (
        ACTIVITY_SEQ,
        OWNER,
        NUMTRAILERS,
        RELEASEFORMRECEIVED
        )
      VALUES (
        input.actseq,
        input.owner,
        input.numtrailers,
        input.releaseformreceived
    );

    Response_out := '';

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        err_num := SQLCODE;
        err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 3900);
        Response_out := TO_CHAR (err_num) || ': ' || err_msg;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to tell from you question exactly what you what, but I gather you want the table that you are merging into ( or on )  to be dynamic. In that case, what you should be using is the [DBMS_SQL](http://www.psoug.org/reference/dbms_sql.html) package to create dynamic SQL